# Is there any way to use "this.remote" inside then?

Tags: intern

Is there any way to use "this.remote" inside then?

```
return this.remote
.findByCssSelector('.myClass')
  .isDisplayed()
  .then(function(disp) {
     // How to use this.remote here?
  })
.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.remote` in a callback by saving a reference before hand, like:

```
var remote = this.remote;
return remote
    .findByCssSelector('.myClass')
    .isDisplayed()
    .then(function (disp) {
        return remote
            .doLeadfootThings()
    })
```

Another option is to use `this.parent`, like:

```
return this.remote
    .findByCssSelector('.myClass')
    .isDisplayed()
    .then(function (disp) {
        return this.parent
            .doLeadfootThings()
    })
```

`this.parent` is a pointer to the parent Command chain, so it has the context of the Command chain at the point of the `then` callback. The difference becomes important for subsequent operations.

```
return remote
    .findById('someTable')
    .then(function () {
        // context of this.parent is #someTable
        return this.parent
            .findByTagName('tr')
            // found TR is the first row in #someTable
            .getVisibleText();
    })
```

vs

```
return remote
    .findById('someTable')
    .then(function () {
        // context of remote is empty
        return remote
            .findByTagName('tr')
            // found TR is the first TF on the page, not necessarily the first
            // in #someTable
            .getVisibleText();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `bind()`

```
return this.remote
    .findByCssSelector('.myClass')
      .isDisplayed()
      .then(function(disp) {
         // How to use this.remote here?
         return this.remote...
      }.bind(this))
    .end();
```